# How do i find the root location of the current node_module

Tags: node.js, npm

I am making an node package to help automate some copy-paste jobs that we seem to do lots at our company.

When running a node command from the command line I am trying to copy a file from the install location of the package within the node_modules folder. I just need something like `module.getInstallPath()`. If anyone knows how to get this path I would be very grateful.

I can't find anything about how to do this anywhere. I've got all the rest of it working but i can't find anywhere how i get the root folder of the installed

Comment: do you mean `const path = require('path'); const mypackagepath = path.resolve('node_modules/your_package_name')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `__dirname`.  It's a module-scoped variable that provides the directory of the current module where it's called.  So for example if your module is installed to `/Users/you/app/node_modules/bob/index.js` then the `__dirname` will be `/Users/you/app/node_modules/bob/`. From the [Node Docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname)

Comment: I’m sure I tried it this and it didn’t work but I must have done something wrong. Thanks for this, I will test in the morning as I’m going to bed now, will mark the answer as correct if it works!

Comment: Accepted as the answer, i must have been confused when i tried this earlier, but this is just what i need. Thanks

Comment: One thing that might've confused you is that it considers the current script file as the "module", so to extend my above example, if you were to package a module to `~/app/node_modules/bob` and then call `__dirname` from the `src` subfolder of the module, the return value would be `/Users/you/app/node_modules/bob/src/`

Comment: Yeah, i think that's what tripped me up, i'm using `path.join('__dirname, '..')` to find the root directory